# how to make progess widget show with the effect?

Tags: jquery-ui

How do I make the widget show    with this effect

when I run this then it wont show?

```
$("#myID").progressbar({ 
        show: { 
            effect: "blind", 
            duration: 800 
        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no show options for a progressbar: http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/

You mean something ike this?:
http://jsfiddle.net/2Zyf8/1/

```
var progressBar = $('#myID');

progressBar.progressbar({
    value: 25,
    create: function (event, ui) {
        var bar = $('.ui-progressbar-value');
        var realWidth = bar.width();
        bar.width(0).animate({
            width: realWidth
        }, 800);
    }
});
```